Unable to install SSDT from docker file for windows docker image
I am trying to create windows image for .NET framework 4.8.
One of my project APPSeCONNECT.Database.sqlproj when getting nuget restored isn't able to find the file.
C:\app\AEC.Platform.Common\AEC.Platform.Database\APPSeCONNECT.Database\APPSeCONNECT.Database.sqlproj(90,56):
error MSB4226: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" was not found. Also, tried to find "Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" in the fallback search path(s) for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) - "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild" . These search paths are defined in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe.Config". Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk in one of the search paths.
Found from internet that I have to add
vs_buildtools.exe
Below is the entire docker file
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 AS build

# Install SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) along with Visual Studio Build Tools
RUN powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_buildtools.exe -OutFile vs_buildtools.exe; \
    Start-Process -FilePath vs_buildtools.exe -ArgumentList '--quiet --wait --norestart --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.DataTools --includeRecommended --includeOptional' -NoNewWindow -Wait; \
    Remove-Item -Force vs_buildtools.exe"

# Verify SSDT installation
RUN cmd /c "dir \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\""

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

COPY AEC.Platform.Apps/AEC.BackgroundService/ /app/AEC.Platform.Apps/AEC.BackgroundService/

# Usefull to see the contents of the directory
# RUN powershell -Command "Get-ChildItem -Recurse 'C:\\app'"

# Copy the common files from the parent directory
COPY AEC.Platform.Common/AEC.Platform.SDK /app/AEC.Platform.Common/AEC.Platform.SDK
COPY AEC.Platform.Common/APPSeConnect.BackgroundServices.Helpers /app/AEC.Platform.Common/APPSeConnect.BackgroundServices.Helpers
COPY AEC.Platform.Common/APPSeConnect.Cloud.Helpers /app/AEC.Platform.Common/APPSeConnect.Cloud.Helpers
COPY AEC.Platform.Common/APPSeConnect.Common /app/AEC.Platform.Common/APPSeConnect.Common
COPY AEC.Platform.Common/APPSeConnect.Data /app/AEC.Platform.Common/APPSeConnect.Data
COPY AEC.Platform.Common/AEC.Platform.Database /app/AEC.Platform.Common/AEC.Platform.Database
COPY AEC.Platform.Common/APPSeConnect.Lib /app/AEC.Platform.Common/APPSeConnect.Lib
COPY AEC.Platform.Common/APPSeConnect.RealTimeCommunication /app/AEC.Platform.Common/APPSeConnect.RealTimeCommunication
COPY AEC.Platform.Common/APPSeConnect.Security /app/AEC.Platform.Common/APPSeConnect.Security
COPY AEC.Platform.Common/Insync.Utils /app/AEC.Platform.Common/Insync.Utils
COPY AEC.Platform.Common/APPSeConnect.Data.DataClasses /app/AEC.Platform.Common/APPSeConnect.Data.DataClasses

# Restore NuGet packages
RUN powershell -Command "nuget restore 'C:\\app\\AEC.Platform.Apps\\AEC.BackgroundService\\AEC.Platform.BackgroundService.sln'"

# Build the solution in Release mode for x64 platform
RUN msbuild /app/AEC.Platform.Apps/AEC.BackgroundService /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="x64"

# Use the official Microsoft .NET Framework runtime image to run the application
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 AS runtime

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the build output from the build stage to the runtime stage
COPY --from=build /app/APPSeConnect.Worker.Console/x64/Debug .

# Define the entry point for the application
ENTRYPOINT ["APPSeConnect.Worker.Console.exe"]

The directory listing using cmd shows no directory named SSDT
06/11/2024  11:42 PM    
    <DIR>          .
    06/11/2024  11:42 PM    <DIR>          ..
    06/11/2024  11:42 PM    <DIR>          Python Tools
    06/11/2024  11:42 PM    <DIR>          Web
    06/11/2024  11:42 PM    <DIR>          WebApplications

Thanks.

I'm running on a quick test on your dockerfile, but while that runs, have you tested that install on a regular VM outside of a container to ensure it goes through?

I tested this dockerfile and got the same results. I also tested outside of a container and also got the same results. I think the command to install the SSDT is incorrect, but could not find an alternative. I'll look a bit more into this

The issue with your dockerfile is the name of the module. The correct name is: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.DataBuildTools. So, the section of your dockerfile should be:
# Install SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) along with Visual Studio Build Tools
RUN powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_buildtools.exe -OutFile vs_buildtools.exe; \
    Start-Process -FilePath vs_buildtools.exe -ArgumentList '--quiet --wait --norestart --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.DataBuildTools --includeRecommended --includeOptional' -NoNewWindow -Wait; \
    Remove-Item -Force vs_buildtools.exe"

